Test loging form in Phoenix liveview
I want to make a test in Peonix liveview that test the login form. My non functional test looks like this:
  test "logs in" do
{:ok, view, html} = live(Phoenix.ConnTest.build_conn(), "/login")
IO.inspect(view
   |> element( ~s{[phx-submit="submit_login"]})
   |> render_submit(%{"username" => "mk", "password" => "123"}))

end
I also tried this with the same result:
test "logs in" do
    {:ok, view, html} = live(Phoenix.ConnTest.build_conn(), "/login") assert view
    |> form(".login-form",  %{username: "mk", password: "123"})
    |> render_submit() =~ "Central hub"
  end

And the login form looks like this:
  <form class="login-form" phx-submit="submit_login">
<div class="p-1 grid place-items-center">
  <label for="username" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Username:</label>
  <input class="login-input" type="text" id="username" name="username" />
</div>

Further, there is an event handler for the form.
  def handle_event("submit_login", %{"username" => username, "password" => password}, socket) do
case Auth.login(username, password) do
   ...
  end 
end

What happens when I run the test is that I get redirected to the error page. I expect to log in. How can I get the field names in my test to match the fields in the login form? I have tried to understand this by reading the Phoenix LiveView test documentation, but I don't understand the examples.

I think you have a typo for the password field in your test. Should that be 'password'  and not 'passwerd'?

Thanks! I corrected the typo but I still have the same problem

Here is my attempt to try and reproduce a project with your error.
I have declared a stub authentication that only checks that the username and password fields are supplied.
# file: lib/phoenix_app/auth.ex
defmodule Auth do
  def login(username, password) do
    # Add your authentication logic here
    # For demonstration purposes, let's assume authentication is successful if username and password are not empty
    if username != "" and password != "" do
      :ok
    else
      :error
    end
  end
end

In the login component, the handler returns a redirect to a secure page if the user authentication is successful.
# file: lib/phoenix_app_web/live/login.ex
defmodule PhoenixAppWeb.Login do
  use PhoenixAppWeb, :live_view

  def handle_event("submit_login", %{"username" => username, "password" => password}, socket) do
    case Auth.login(username, password) do
      :ok ->
        IO.puts("Login successful")
        {:noreply, redirect(socket, to: "/secure")}

      :error ->
        IO.puts("Login failed")
        {:noreply, socket}
    end
  end
end

The corresponding template is declared in lib/phoenix_app_web/live/login.html.heex
<form class="login-form" phx-submit="submit_login">
  <div class="p-1 grid place-items-center">
    <label for="username" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Username:</label>
    <input class="login-input" type="text" id="username" name="username" />
    <label for="password" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Password:</label>
    <input class="login-input" type="text" id="password" name="password" />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>

The configured route declares the following live pages in the root scope.
  scope "/", PhoenixAppWeb do
    pipe_through :browser

    get "/", PageController, :index

    live "/secure", Secure
    live "/login", Login
  end

And for the login test, we import the Phoenix.LiveViewTest module.
defmodule PhoenixAppWeb.LoginTest do
  use PhoenixAppWeb.ConnCase
  import Phoenix.LiveViewTest

  test "logs in" do
    conn = build_conn()

    {:ok, view, _html} = live(conn, "/login")

    response =
      view
      |> element(~s{[phx-submit="submit_login"]})
      |> render_submit(%{"username" => "mk", "password" => "123"})

    assert {:error, {:redirect, %{to: "/secure"}}} = response
  end
end

We can run our test with the command
mix test test/phoenix_app_web/live/

The complete REPL is available here.

If there is a push_redirect or a redirect at the end of the handle_event you can't assert value on the page you're redirected to. You have to assert that the redirection is done to the right path and create another test module to test the next page.
@impl true
def handle_event("submit_login", %{"username" => username, "password" => password}, socket) do
    case Auth.login(username, password) do
        %User{id: user_id} ->
            {:noreply,
                socket
                |> push_redirect(
                    to: Routes.user_path(socket, :show, user_id)
                )
            }
        _ ->
            {:noreply, socket |> put_flash(:error, "Wrong username/password")}
    end
end

Here you have to test:
test "handle_event submit_login", %{conn: conn} do
    {:ok, view, _} = live(conn, "/login")
    user_id = 1
    submit =
        view
        |> form("form[phx-submit=submit_login]", %{username: "mk", password: "123"})
        |> render_submit()

    assert submit == {:error, {:live_redirect, %{to: Routes.user_path(conn, :show, user_id)}}}
end

And then to test:
test "user path mount", %{conn: conn} do
    user_id = 1
    {:ok, _, html} = live(conn, Routes.user_path(conn, :show, user_id))
    assert html =~ "Central hub"
end

